# argument missing && || operators in parenthesis but still working

Tags: javascript, syntax

I have come across this piece of code where the if statement contains an argument without `&&` and/or `||` operators.

```
if (event.target.scrollTop > 0 !== isViewScrolled) {
    //do something
}
```

How is it possible that this works? What is the logic contained in the parentheses?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Not every `if` has multiple expressions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check operator precedence https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

According to the above `>` (greater than) has higher precedence than `!=` (inequality) so the

```
event.target.scrollTop > 0 !== isViewScrolled
```

is equivalent to

```
(event.target.scrollTop > 0) !== isViewScrolled
```

Although both are equivalent it's best to include parentheses where the order of  evaluation is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

`(event.target.scrollTop > 0` returns a bool, so javascript just checks if this bool is equal to `isViewScrolled`